# In CMD substitution, how to remove substring which starts from specific character to the end

Tags: string, cmd, substitution

In substitution or deletion of sub string from original string, usually uses this form in windows CMD.

```
set result=%original:<strings_to_be_removed>=<strngs_to_be_newly_substituted>%
```

So it works for many situation as follows ..

```
set "original=Questions that may already have your answer"

set "you=%original:that=you%"
set you
you=Questions you may already have your answer

set challenge=%original:Questions=Challenges%
set challenge
challenge=Challenges that may already have your answer

set answer=%original:*your=%
set answer
answer= answer
```

But I don't know how to substitute or remove sub-string which starts from specific character(or word) to the end of the original string.

For example, suppose I would like to remove sub-string which starts from "that" to the end of the original string. Then I use command as follows and expect result string to be "Questions "

```
set result=%original:that*=%
```

But, result string has no difference from original string. No effect occures. Substitution intention fails..

```
set result
result=Questions that may already have your answer
```

I used escape character '^', '\' for this case, but no effect..

How to fix this to substitute or remove substring like this type?

How can you substitute or remove substring which starts from specific character(or word) to the end of the original string? Thank you:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can trick the command line parser to do that:

```
set "original=Questions that may already have your answer"
set result=%original: may =&REM %
set result
```

sadly, `set "result=%original:may=&REM %"` doesn't work, so the string should be free from poison characters.

How it works:

replace the word with `&REM`, which makes your string:

```
Questions that  & REM already have your answer
```

and the command:

```
set result=Questions that  & REM already have your answer
```

`&` is used as a delimiter for commands (try `echo hello&echo world`, which executes both echo commands). So what's really executed, is two commands:

```
set result=Questions that
```

and

```
REM already have your answer
```

It also doesn't work with delayed expansion. You can use a subfunction for it instead:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if 1==1 (
  set "original=Questions that may already have your answer"
  call :substring "!original!"
  set result
)
goto :eof

:substring
set org=%~1
set result=%org: may =&REM %
goto :eof
```

Comment: Note: this is no intended feature - more like an ugly hack, (ab)using the way the interpreter works.

Comment: Additionally, "&::" works too. Would you please tell me about '&' role in this case ?

Comment: get used to use `REM`. `::` is technically a (invalid) label, and can give you unexpected results in certain circumstances.

Comment: But in application with delayedexpansion mode, it seems not wok. For example, #1) set result=!original:that=&REM !", #2) set result,  #3) result=Questions &REM  may already have your answer, #4) echo !result!, #4) Questions &REM  may already have your answer, #5) echo %result%, #6) Questions , #7) echo "%result%", #8) "Questions &REM  may already have your answer"

Comment: Delayed expansion is parsed differently. That's the problem with hacks...

Comment: Thanks for additional detailed explanation and solution in the case of delayed expansion. Until a spell ago, I decided to use powershell replace as follows.<# echo !original:that=&::! | powershell -command "$input -replace 'that.*','' " >tmp.txt & set /p result=<tmp.txt & set result #>  It works fine too, but flickering of file creation & deletion(tmp.txt) inside the file explorer feels like uncomfortable. So your solution is very welcome & I'm really really grateful to you. Thank you:-)